# Using Html.DropDownListFor to list data from one table, but save it to another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

On the Create action, I can add information into editor fields and save them to Table1, however, for one of the fields I want a drop down list, populated from a column from Table2, which can then be selected and saved to Table1 in one of the fields, depending on selection. I have managed to display the information in a drop down table from Table2, but not pass it to Table1

Model1:

```
public int id { get; set; }
    public string JobNo { get; set; }
    public string DelNo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DeptToPack { get; set; }
    public string PackNo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> TargetHrs { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> PackingDate { get; set; } 
    public virtual Table2 Table2{ get; set; }
```

Model 2:

```
public Table2()
{
    this.Table1= new HashSet<Table1>();
}

public int id { get; set; }
public string Dept { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Table1> Table1{ get; set; }
```

Combined Model:

```
public class Combined
    {
        public Table1 Table1 { get; set; }
        public Table2 Table2{ get; set; }
     }
```

The view currently displays text editors for all the fields which can be edited and saved to a database using SaveChanges(); on the HomeController, under a Create action

Create Action

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {


            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = _db.Table2
                .Select(c => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = c.Dept,
                    Text = c.Dept
                });

            ViewBag.Dropdownlist = items;


            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Table1 table1)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _db.Table1.Add(table1);
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(table1);
        }
```

And the view displays the information from table1, and one field from table2. I seem to be having trouble with the @Html.DropDownList element

I currently have (below) which displays the data, but cannot be processed to Table1

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Table1.Field1", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.DropDownList)
```

Hopefully the image explains it better, filled input boxes will be saved to Table1
except for 1 field, which is a drop down list from column {InfoToPass}, from Table2, in which 1 of 4 options can be selected, then that value along with all the other inputs will be saved to Table1

[image]

Comment: Have you found a solution for your problem. If so can you please share it ?

Comment: I've nearly got it, just making some tweaks then I'll post my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My scenario involved joining a few tables to provide a certain column value, (so you can ignore then linq query), which would displayed in a drop down list. The user can then select the values (if any) from the drop down list which can then be saved to another table (*Table1*).

**Create View:**

```
    @model TharInfo2.Models.Combined

    <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Table1.DelNo, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Rev)
    </div>
```

**Create Controller:**

```
        public ActionResult Create()
            {
            var rd = RouteData.Values["jobno"];
            var query = (from t in _db.table3
                         join d in _db.table2 on t.delivery_number equals d.ID
                         join m in _db.table4 on d.OrderNo equals m.JobNo
                         where m.JobNo == rd
                         select new
                              {
                                  t.rev_delivery_number
                              });


             IEnumerable<SelectListItem> rev_del = query
                        .Select(c => new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Value = c.rev_delivery_number,
                            Text = c.rev_delivery_number
                        });


             ViewBag.Rev = rev_del;


             return View();
             }




                [HttpPost]
                public ActionResult Create(Table1 table1)
                {



                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        _db.Table1.Add(table1);
                        _db.SaveChanges();
                        return RedirectPermanent("Index");


                    }

                    return View(table1);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a table1 object and pass the relevant values to it from the object being passed into the controller, then do the same with a new table2 object and the parameters that are relevant to it. Once both are appropriately populated, save to their respective tables and save changes.

After sorting out the two objects you will end with somethign like this to save:

```
_db.Table2.Add(table2);
_db.Table1.Add(table1);
_db.SaveChanges();
```